# Частичная специализация шаблона класса C++

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся  со следующей проблемой: пишу класс матриц, и мне хотелось бы чтобы можно было задавать как фиксированные в compile-time размеры матрицы, так и динамически изменяемые. Весь проект должен быть в духе boost или stl, поэтому я написал два класса массивов, которые используются в классе матрицы для хранения значений. Вот их укороченное объявление:

```
template<
    typename T, 
    typename _Derived
>
struct _Vector_base // базовый класс векторов: предназначен для typedef
{
public:
    typedef _Vector_base<T, _Derived> base_type;

    typedef T value_type;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;
    typedef pointer iterator;
    typedef const_pointer const_iterator;
};

template<
    typename _Scalar
>
class vector : // класс динамического вектора
    _Vector_base<_Scalar, vector<_Scalar> >
{
   // ...
};

template<
    typename _Scalar, 
    size_t _Size
> 
class fixed_vector : // класс фиксированного вектора
    _Vector_base<_Scalar, fixed_vector<_Scalar, _Size> >
{
   // ...
};

template<
    typename _Scalar, 
    typename _Container
>
class _Matrix // Базовый класс всех матриц - typedef'ы и вспомогательные методы
{
public:
    typedef _Matrix<_Scalar, _Container> base_type;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef _Scalar value_type;
    typedef _Scalar* pointer;
    typedef _Scalar& reference;
    typedef const _Scalar* const_pointer;
    typedef const _Scalar& const_reference;
    typedef _Container container_type;

    _Matrix() : 
        nrows(0), ncols(0) {
    }
    _Matrix(size_t n, size_t m) : 
        nrows(n), ncols(m){
    }

    inline size_type size() const { return (nrows * ncols); }

    inline size_type rows() const { return nrows; }
    inline size_type columns() const { return ncols; }

    inline bool empty() const { return ((nrows == 0) && (ncols == 0)); }

protected:
    size_t nrows, ncols;
    _Container m;

}; // end class _Matrix

// класс динамических матриц (общий случай)
template<
    typename _Scalar,
    typename _Container = vector<_Scalar>
>
class matrix : 
    public _Matrix<_Scalar, _Container>
{
public:
    matrix(size_t _Rows, size_t _Cols) : 
        _Matrix(_Rows, _Cols)
    {

    }
};

// частичная специализация класса матриц для матриц фиксированного размера
template<
    typename _Scalar,
    size_t _Rows,
    size_t _Cols
>
class matrix<_Scalar, fixed_vector<_Scalar, (_Rows * _Cols)> > :
    public _Matrix<_Scalar, fixed_vector<_Scalar, _Rows*_Cols> >
{
public:
    matrix() :
        _Matrix(_Rows, _Cols)
    { 
    }
};
```

Я предполагал, что использование будет примерно таким:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   matrix<float> m(2, 2); // динамическая матрица
   matrix<float, 2, 2> x; // фиксированная матрица
   return 0;
}
```

Однако, компилятор (MS Visual Studio 2012) такое не пропускает:

```
ClCompile:
  main.cpp
..\main.cpp(62): error C2977: 'matrix' : too many template arguments
..\main.cpp(12): see declaration of 'matrix'
..\main.cpp(62): error C2133: 'x' : unknown size
..\main.cpp(62): error C2512: 'matrix' : no appropriate default constructor available

Build FAILED.
```

Собственно вопрос: возможно ли такое скомпилировать или что-то противоречит правилам C++? И если да то как это сделать?

В принципе я бы мог сделать отдельный класс для фиксированных матриц (например, `fixed_matrix<T, N>`), но все же интересно разобраться почему именно этот вариант не проходит.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет-нет, частичная специализация работает не так.

Идея частичной специализации состоит в том, что у вас *фиксированный* список аргументов шаблона, но для некоторых случаев он раскрывается по-другому. Например:

```
template<typename T> class Container
{
    // имплементация по умолчанию
};

template<typename T> class Container<T*>
{
    // специальная имплементация для указателя
};

template<typename ARG, typename RET> class Container<RET(ARG)>
{
    // специальная имплементация для функций ARG -> RET
};
```

Когда вы пишете, к примеру, `Container<int*>`, компилятор проверяет: не подходит ли какой-нибудь специальный случай? Нельзя ли тип `int*` представить в виде `T*` для какого-нибудь `T`? Если оказалось, что можно (для `T = int`) — компилятор использует нужную имплементацию.

Теперь для вашего случая. Можно попробовать такой вот трюк:

```
template<
    typename _Scalar,
    typename _Container,
    size_t _Rows = 0,
    size_t _Cols = 0
>
// общий случай, размер не нулевой, фиксированный
class matrix : 
    public _Matrix<_Scalar, _Container>
{
public:
    matrix() : 
        _Matrix(_Rows, _Cols)
    {
        static_assert(_Rows > 0 && _Cols > 0,
                      "both _Rows and _Cols must be either 0 or > 0");    
    }
};

template<
    typename _Scalar,
>
class matrix<_Scalar, _Container, 0, 0> :
    public _Matrix<_Scalar, _Container>
{
public:
    matrix(size_t _Rows, size_t _Cols) :
        _Matrix(_Rows, _Cols)
    { 
    }
};
```

(Вот рабочая реализация: http://ideone.com/kK66HH.)

Если такое не подойдёт, всегда можно просто объявить два разных шаблона: `matrix` и `fixed_matrix`.